# Roll-forward is required following the Restore

Tags: db2, database-backups, db2-luw

I have three different databases for my different environments (`hsprd`, `hstst`,`hstrn`). `hsprd` is my production environment with live data.

Every so often, a request comes through to restore production data to `hstrn` or `hstst`. I typically run this command (after stopping, then dropping the db):

`db2 restore db hsprd taken at 20140331180002 to /dbs into hstrn newlogpath /dbs/log/hstrn without rolling forward;`

When running this, I receive this message:

`SQL2537N  Roll-forward is required following the Restore.`

Could someone advise how to fix this?

Thanks.

edit: My backups are here:

```
(/home/dbtmp/backups)> ll                            
total 22791416
-rwxrwxr-x    1 hsprd    cics     11669123072 Mar 31 18:03 HSPRD.0.hsprd.NODE0000.CATN0000.20140331180002.001
```

After restoring my database and omitting `without rolling forward`, I receive this message when trying to query the database:

`SQL1117N  A connection to or activation of database "HSTRN" cannot be made 
because of ROLL-FORWARD PENDING.  SQLSTATE=57019`

When I try to rollforward, with this command, I receive this response:

```
(/home/dbtmp/backups)> db2 rollforward db hstrn to end of backup and complete;
SQL4970N  Roll-forward recovery on database "HSTRN" cannot reach the specified 
stop point (end-of-log or point-in-time) on database partition(s) "0". 
Roll-forward recovery processing has halted on log file "S0006353.LOG".
```

Comment: Is there something in the error message that seems confusing?

Comment: I should have been more clear, I've added my findings after completing the restore, @mustaccio.

Comment: I think the other error message is equally clear. It might help to read the error explanation: `db2 \? SQL1117N`

Comment: Updated my question after an attempted rollforward.

Comment: Assuming the logs are included in the backup image, you'll need to specify the `LOGTARGET` option on the `RESTORE` command to extract them, presumably to the `NEWLOGPATH` location. Since you say you _typically run this command_, I wonder how that's been working until now.

Comment: @mustaccio that worked for me. Feel free to make this the answer to help others, or I will close. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error suggests that you are restoring an online backup, which must be rolled forward. Alternatively, use an offline backup image, then you can include the `without rolling forward` option.

The second error means that you need to issue the `ROLLFORWARD` command before you can use the database restored from an online backup.

Finally the third error means that the `ROLLFORWARD` command is unable to find the logs required for it to succeed. Assuming the logs are included in the backup image, you'll need to specify the `LOGTARGET` option on the `RESTORE` command to extract them, presumably to the `NEWLOGPATH` location.