# DB2- restore from another server

Tags: db2, database-restore, db2-luw

My problem is very similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22793888/roll-forward-is-required-following-the-restore).

I have tried numerous combinations to no avail. On ServerA, I created a backup with this command:

```
db2 backup db mydb user myuser using mypass online to
c:\db-backup\local include logs without prompting
```

I then copied that file to ServerB, and ran:

```
db2 => restore database mydb user myuser using mypass from C:\
TAKEN AT 20151001060002 logtarget C:\DB2\NODE0000\LOGS replace
existing without prompting
```

I'm uncertain on how to properly handle the logtarget, and the result of that command was this warning:

```
SQL2540W  Restore is successful, however a warning "2523" was
encountere during Database Restore while processing in No Interrupt
mode.
```

I read up on the warning, and it seemed appropriate for what I was doing:

```
SQL2523W  Warning! Restoring to an existing database that is different
from the database on the backup image, but have matching names. (more)
```

Then I ran this:

```
db2 => rollforward database mydb user myuser using mypass to end of
logs and stop
```

And received this:

```
SQL1268N  Roll-forward recovery stopped due to error "1" while
retrieving log file "S0002796.LOG" for database "MYDB" on node "0".
```

I've tried numerous combinations like this:

```
db2 => restore database mydb user myuser using mypass from C:\ TAKEN
AT 20151001060002 WITHOUT ROLLING FORWARD
```

And got this:

```
SQL2537N  Roll-forward is required following the Restore.
```

I'm now stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `rollforward database mydb user myuser using mypass to end of
logs overflow log path (C:\DB2\NODE0000\LOGS)` (here's hoping that this is not the active log directory).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately I get this error again `SQL1268N  Roll-forward recovery stopped due to error "1" while retrieving log file "S0002797.LOG" for database "MYDB" on node "0". ` The log path I'm supplying is just an empty directory, does it need to be a specific location?

Comment: Then add `noretrieve` option. Why "C:\DB2\NODE0000\LOGS" anyway?

Comment: That worked, thank you very much. I ran this command `db2 rollforward database mydb user myuser using mypass to end of logs and
stop overflow log path (C:\DB2\NODE0000\LOGS) noretrieve`. If you would like to add an answer to this post so I can accept it. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is arising from the fact that, since you are restoring your backup over an existing database, DB2 gets confused between two different log streams when trying to roll forward the database.

The `logtarget` clause in your `restore` command specifies where to extract the logs contained in the backup image from ServerA. However, these logs are not automatically used for rollforward; the command will attempt to find logs in the active log directory. However, on ServerB the active log directory contains a different log stream that belongs to the database that you are replacing, so the first log in sequence from ServerA, `S0002796.LOG` is not there.

You use the `overflow log path` option for the rollforward command to indicate an alternative location where it should look for log files; it would be the directory where you extracted logs during the restore:

```
rollforward database mydb user myuser using mypass to end of logs 
  overflow log path (C:\DB2\NODE0000\LOGS)
```

However, that's not all. Now that `rollforward` finds `S0002796.LOG`, and since you have specified `to end of logs`, it will attempt to find subsequent logs in the stream from ServerA. Apparently, only `S0002796.LOG` was included in the backup image, so `S0002797.LOG` must be elsewhere, meaning in the active or archive log path -- only it's not there, because on ServerB a different log stream is maintained.

To prevent `rollforward` from looking for log files not present in `overflow log path` add the option `noretrieve`. The final command would be, as you say:

```
rollforward database mydb user myuser using mypass to end of logs 
  overflow log path (C:\DB2\NODE0000\LOGS) 
  noretrieve
```